# LaTex tightemize bulletpoint indent for multilines

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I would like to indent the bulletpoints of "THIS IS RUNSUBSECTION" to have equal spacing with the "COMPILER" subsection. I am using tightemize which I believe is a part of the fancyhdr package. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\lastupdated

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}

\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.59\textwidth}

\section{Work Experience}
\runsubsection{ABC}
\descript{| HELLO MY NAME}
\location{June 2019 - Present | HI, WORLD}
This is a random statement to fill in some blank space and I am not sure what else to put in here  \\
\sectionsep

\hspace{1.1em}\runsubsection{This is runsubsection}
\descript{| ABCDEFGH IJKLMNO PQR }
\hspace{1em}\descript{STUVWXY ZABCDEFGHIJKLM}
\hspace{1em}\location{June 2019 - Present | HI, WORLD}
\vspace{\topsep}
\begin{tightemize}
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence. Sometimes a random word just isn't enough
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching 
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching 
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep


\hspace{1.0em}\runsubsection{This is runsubsection}
\descript{| ABC }
\hspace{1em}\location{June 2019 - Present | HI, WORLD}
\begin{tightemize}
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence. 
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here 
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence. If you're visiting this page, you're likely 
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence. 
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{COMPILER}
\descript{| WORLD | HELLO}
\location{June 2019 - Present | HI, WORLD}
\begin{tightemize}
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence. Sometimes a random word just isn't enough, and that is where the random
\item If you're visiting this page, you're likely here because you're searching for a random sentence. Sometimes a random word is enough
\end{tightemize}


\end{minipage}
\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Never heard of this environment and fancyhdr does not tackle lists, but headers and footers in pages.

Comment: The bullets of the three lists are perfectly  aligned in your code. Only the "rubsubsections"  are misaligned, that is the expected when you add different spaces before (but only sometimes ...).

Comment: The environment is defined in the custom document class, not in  `fancyhdr`. On the other hand,  the play also with vertical space (`\vspace`,`\sectionsep`) because the class implement some new commands with *negative* vertical spaces (`-\topsep`,`-\parskip`) is as amusing as a  toothache.

Comment: Hello everyone! Bernard thank you for pointing that out! Fran the bulletpoints are aligned and I do not want that. I would like the lists of the first 2 runsubsections to have an indentation to align with the overall style of the third list. i.e header -> indent bullet points

Comment: @Fran  any ideas

Comment: @Bernard any ideas?

Comment: The whole `tightemize` environment is a list environment, and that environment make the bullet points, so I don't know what you mean by "list", but I will explain my first comment in another way: Remove **all** the horizontal spaces added manually  (like `\hspace {1.1.em}`, `\hspace {1em}, etc. ) and check. Is that what you want?.

Comment: @Fran Thank you for the clarification, I appreciate it. The reason the hspace is there, is because I would like my second and third 'runsubsection' to be indented, as well as the bulletpoints, to indicate that it is grouped under the first 'runsubsection'. Under section 'Work Experience' I will have one runsubsection indicating  the job (runsubsection one) and projects associated with that job (runsubsections two and three). Runsubsection four is a different job and I want to make that distinction. If you have another way to do it please let me know.

Comment: My way is not use a custom class (this seems to me specially expendable). About spacing, you should start  learning about `\parindent` and `\parskip`.

Comment: @Fran I will take a look into that, thank ya!